# How to achieve high speed processing receiving from Azure Event Hub?

Tags: azure, producer-consumer, azure-eventhub

I am working on the POC for Azure Event hubs to implement the same into our application.

**Quick Brief on flow.**

- Created tool to read the CSV data from local folder and send it to       event hub.
- We are sending Event Data in Batch to event hub.
- With 12 instance of tool (Parallel), I can send a total of 600 000 lines of messages to Event hub within 1 min.
- But, On receiver side, to receive the 600 000 lines of data, it takes more than 10 mins.

**Need to achieve**

- I would like to Match/double my egress speed on the receiver to
  process the data. Existing Configuration

**The configuration I have made user are**

- TU - 10 One Event hub with 32 Partition.
- Coding logic goes same as mentioned in [MSDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/)
- Only difference is, I am sending line of data in a batch.
  EventProcessorhost with options {MaxBatchSize= 1000000,
  PrefetchCount=1000000

Answer (score 2):

To achieve higher egress rate (aka faster processing pipeline) in eventhubs:

1. Create a Scaled-out pipeline - each partition in EventHub is the `unit-of-scale` for processing events out of EventHub. With the Scale you described (**6Lakh events per min --> 10K events per sec - with 32 partitions - you already got this right**). Make sure you create as many partitions as you envision your pipeline need in near future. Imagine analyzing traffic on a Highway and no. of lanes is the only limitation for the amount of traffic.
2. Equal load distribution across partitions: if you are using SendToASpecificPartition or SendUsingPartitionKey - you will need to take care of equal load distribution. If you use `EventHubClient.Send(EventDataWithOutPartitionKey)` - EventHubs service will make sure all of your partitions are equally loaded. If a single EventHub Partition is heavily loaded - the amount of time you can process all events on EventHub will be bound by no. of events on this Partition.
3. Scale-out physical resources on the `Receiver`/[`EventProcessorHost`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2015/01/16/event-processor-host-best-practices-part-1/): most importantly Network (Sockets & bandwidth) & after-a-point, CPU & Memory. Use `PartitionManagerOptions.MaxReceiveClients` to increase the maximum number of `EventHubClient`s (which has a dedicated `MessagingFactory`, which maps to 1 `socket`) created per `EventProcessorHost` instance. By default it is `16`.

Let me know how it went... :)

[More on Event Hubs.](https://link.medium.com/ZFqhxR8myW)

Comment: Hi Sreeram, on point 1 : Ingress is taking 6 lacks Event/minute by 12 instance of sender. event hub still the 32 partiotion. Point 2 : I am using EventHubClient.Send(EventDataWithOutPartitionKey) , so that event processor host can manage the load.  Point 3: I would like to get more details on MessageFactory respect to Eventhub. Could you please share sample example to refer?  [Note]: I am using below constructor of Eventprocessorhost public EventProcessorHost(string hostName, string eventHubPath, string consumerGroupName, string eventHubConnectionString, string storageConnectionString);

Comment: Hi Anil, I had to revisit point (3) - pl. do take a look. Also, make sure that the EventHubs receive is your real bottleneck - remove any blocking I/O calls in `IEventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync` (eliminate the possibility that your `ProcessEventsAsync` is not contributing to the 10 min..

Comment: Hi @Sreeram ,  I tried increasing the TU to 20 and found, 6 Lacks messages processed in 5 min (earlier 10 min). I would like to increase the Event hub partition to 100 (can create new one with 100 Partition) and check for load testing. Is there way to increase/create new EH with 100 Partition? I would like to check all higher possibility before going to use this for my application.